# Identifying the process of internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, process, microsoft-edge

Can anybody explain me what this process means ?

**--from-ie-to-edge=3 --ie-frame-hwnd=b0fd4**

Comment: I tried searching for these you mentioned, but failed. Are they command line arguments that are appended when running the application? As far as I know there is no such command line argument for Microsoft Edge. If possible, could you provide more details?

Comment: This was identified via CrowdStrike Portal while investigating network connections.  This is the command line 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --from-ie-to-edge=3 --ie-frame-hwnd=b0fd4

Comment: Well, thanks for your reply. But even I cannot launch Edge with this command you provided, so I'm afraid I cannot get more info about this.